# scheme macro produces unexpected result

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

Does someone know why the following produces the expected result - (2 4 6)

```
(defmacro mult2 (lst)
  (define (itter x)
    (list '* 2 x))
  `(list ,@(map itter lst))) 

(mult2 (1 2 3))
```

while I expected that this one would (with the list identifier)

```
(defmacro mult2 (lst)
  (define (itter x)
    (list '* 2 x))
  `(list ,@(map itter lst)))

(mult2 '(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `'(1 2 3)` is expanded by the reader into `(quote (1 2 3))`. Since you only destructure one list in your macro, it won't work as expected.

Some general advice: if you're working in Racket you probably want to avoid using `defmacro`. That is definitely not the idiomatic way to write macros. Take a look at [syntax-rules](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/guide/pattern-macros.html) and, if you want to define more complicated macros, [syntax-parse](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html). Eli also wrote an [article](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/04/writing-syntax-case-macros.html) explaining syntax-case for people used to defmacro.

Comment: Thanks alot!! You definitely saved me a few hours.

Answer (score 4):

Macro "arguments" are not evaluated. So, when you pass in `'(1 2 3)`, i.e., `(quote (1 2 3))`, that is exactly what the macro sees.

P.S. You are much better off using hygienic macros in Scheme. Here's an example using `syntax-case`:

```
(define-syntax mult2
  (lambda (stx)
    (define (double x)
      #`(* 2 #,x))
    (syntax-case stx ()
      ((_ lst)
       #`(list #,@(map double (syntax-e #'lst)))))))
```

(That's still not how such a macro is idiomatically written, but I tried to mirror your version as closely as possible.)